# How to change a color of Collada using a button in threejs?

Tags: three.js, collada

I want to create a skeleton model with interactive bones so that if you click one of the buttons some part of the skeleton would change color.

I have tried to add two same models in the same spot but with different colors but it caused my Collada model to don't rotate on the y-axis.

```html
<body>
    <script src="js/three.js"></script>                 
    <script src="js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>              
    
    <script>

        if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

        var container;
        var camera, scene, renderer, objects;           
        var dae;            
        var dae2;                   
        var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
        
        loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
        var url='obj/szkieletCube.dae';  
        
        loader.load( url, function ( collada ) {
            dae = collada.scene;
            dae.traverse( function ( child ) {
                if ( child instanceof THREE.SkinnedMesh ) {
                    var animation = new THREE.Animation( child, child.geometry.animation );
                    animation.play();
                }
            } );
            
            dae.scale.x = dae.scale.y = dae.scale.z = 100; 
            dae.rotation.y+=Math.PI/2;
            dae.position.y-=2048;
            dae.position.x-=0;
            dae.position.z+=0;
            dae.updateMatrix();
                        
            dae.traverse( function ( child ) {  
                child.castShadow = true;
                child.receiveShadow = false;
            } );            
            
            init();
            animate();
        } );            

        function init() 
        {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 40000 );
            camera.position.set( Math.pow(2,13), 1024, 0);

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            scene.add( dae );

            var light1  = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
            light1.position.set(1, 1, 1);   
            scene.add( light1 );
        
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight); 
            renderer.shadowMapEnabled=true;
            renderer.shadowMapType=THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }
        
        
        function onWindowResize() {                 

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        }

        function animate() {                
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
        }
        var kat = 0;
        function render() {
            camera.position.y = 1024;
            kat -= -0.001;
            dae.rotation.y = Math.cos( kat ) * 10;
            camera.lookAt( scene.position );        
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: It seems your code is based on a very old version of `ColladaLoader`. Use the following example as a starter template which works with the latest version of `three.js` (`R100`): https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_collada_skinning

Answer (score 0):

See, you use [SkinnedMesh](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/SkinnedMesh) here, which is derived class from [Mesh](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Mesh)
Mesh itself has [Mesh.material](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Mesh.material) property.

So all what you need to change colors, is to collect children, so that you can access them individually on button click handler.

Here's you code adjusted:

```js
var daeChildren = {}; // map dae child name => child node
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();

loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
var url='obj/szkieletCube.dae';  

loader.load( url, function ( collada ) {
    dae = collada.scene;

    ...

    dae.traverse( function ( child ) {  
        child.castShadow = true;
        child.receiveShadow = false;

        // 1. Collect DAE children here
        daeChildren[child.name] = child;
    } );            

    ...

} );
```

And then on button click you can change the material color:

```js
function handleButtonClick() {
    // 2. drop texture if you need the mesh to be just colored
    daeChildren[child.name].material.map = null;

    // 3. set mesh color red
    daeChildren[child.name].material.color = new THREE.Color( 0xff0000 );

    // 4. tell threejs that material must be updated
    daeChildren[child.name].material.needsUpdate = true;
}
```